# CSRF is invalid on REST POST method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have applied CSRF on jsp and freemarker in my project and it is working well.

Below is the code for specifying Web urls in spring-security.xml

```
<http xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        access-denied-page="/accessdenied" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        create-session="ifRequired">


        <intercept-url pattern="/register" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <form-login login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="mySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout=true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
            invalidate-session="true" />
       <csrf/>

    </http>
```

Below is the code of spring-security.xml in for REST API.I also tried to ad CSRF tag in REST HTTP tag but it is not working as well.

```
<http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/api/addpatient" access="ROLE_ADMIN"
            method="POST" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/addpatient/image/{p_id}"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN" method="POST" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/patients" access="ROLE_ADMIN"
            method="GET" />

        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- <csrf /> -->
        <!-- <http-basic/> <form-login login-processing-url="/api" authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler" 
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" /> -->
    </http>
```

All the POST methods in REST and web urls are working fine where I have apllied security or added in security files. But I want a single REST url to register new user without applying any security.

When I send the data from postman I get the following console exception:

```
"10:09:48,749 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
10:09:48,749 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
10:10:10,723 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/adduser'; against '/oauth/token'
10:10:10,726 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/adduser'; against '/api/**'
10:10:10,726 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /adduser at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
10:10:10,726 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:136 - No HttpSession currently exists
10:10:10,726 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:90 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
10:10:10,726 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /adduser at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
10:10:10,726 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /adduser at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
10:10:10,727 DEBUG CsrfFilter:95 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:1522/si-server/adduser
enter into denied page
10:10:10,731 DEBUG cache:83 - Could not find template in cache, creating new one; id=["denied.ftl"["en_US",Cp1252,parsed] ]
10:10:10,791 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
10:10:10,792 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:300 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
10:10:10,797 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed"
```

P.S.
Only REST without security is not working in contrast to the web url where I am doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding the role "ROLE_ANONYMOUS" since you don't want the security to be applied to the URL "/adduser".

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/adduser*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried adding "ROLE_ANONYMOUS" as well as security="none" and filters="none". But it is still not working.